# Swift Standard Libraries are embedded into app for macOSVersion <10.15 even when not required( with swift version 5 )

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode14

I created a sample app that have nothing else but "import AppKit". with Xcode version 14.2, minimum  deployment macOS target 10.13, `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` is set to No, swift version is 5, This embeds all swift libraries though not required making app Size around 11MB.

When the version is changed to 10.15+, size of app is 76KB.

Please suggest a possible work around to include the libraries that are required in version < 10.15